# Algebraic manipulation of probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random vectors that have the same continuous distribution.

If $A$ and $B$ are constant matrices and $AX$ and $BY$ have the same distribution does this imply that $A=B$? Are there any straightforward conditions which make $A=B$?

More generally, when are algebraic manipulations appropriate when dealing with distributions i.e. if $AX+C \stackrel{d}{=} BY+D$ and $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$ does this imply that $A=B$ and $C=D$? Do $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ need to be constants (or are they equal even if they are themselves distributions)?

**Edit** Removed an incorrect calculation.

Comment: No, try $A=I$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $X=Y$ i.i.d. The trouble in your solution starts when you equate the condition $AX\leqslant x$ with $X\leqslant A^{-1}x$ (whose very meaning is actually unclear, are you comparing *vectors*?).

Comment: Yes, $x$ was intended to be a vector. Are you saying that $Pr(AX\leq x) \neq P(X\leq A^{-1}x)$ because the dimensions $x$ and $A^{-1}x$ are not the same?

Comment: No, and why would I say that since when $A$ is square these do have the same dimension? Rather I am stressing that $AX\leqslant x$ and $X\leqslant A^{-1}x$ need to be given a meaning and that if this meaning is a componentwise comparison then there is no reason to expect that these are equivalent.

Comment: Okay, I see so my strategy isn't correct (I was thinking about the change of variable formula for densities where need division by determinant).